# Send/Recieve Error in outlook when getting email from SmarterMail on VPS

Tags: windows-server-2008, vps, microsoft-outlook-2013

I originally had a Shared web host which my domain biggsoftware.co.uk was hosted at.

I then created a VPS running windows server 2008 (not R2) and wanted to point my domain to the VPS and then shutdown the shared hosting site. I got this part to work fine and when typing in biggsoftware.co.uk it took me to my new website.

So far so good, now I realized I would lose my email accounts such as admin@biggsoftware.co.uk when I shutdown the shared hosting so I googled about discovered SmarterMail and installed this on my VPS.

I then created a dns MX record for mail.biggsoftware.co.uk. I added the account admin@biggsoftware.co.uk to outlook 2013 and did some test send and receives. Everything worked fine and I logged into my VPS to verify the emails.

So at this point everything was set and working. I then told my web host to shutdown the shared hosting as it was no longer needed. This took around 3 weeks before the site went down. Around the same time the site went down I started getting the following error in outlook.

Task 'admin@biggsoftware.co.uk - Receiving' reported error (0x80042108): 'Outlook cannot connect to your incoming (POP3) e-mail server. If you continue to receive this message, contact your server administrator or Internet Service Provider (ISP)

Googling this error seem to bring up the same information about firewall/antivirus but I haven't changed anything and my other accounts in outlook work fine.

I have checked the account settings in outlook and it is using mail.biggsoftware.co.uk as the pop and smtp so I can't see why it could be related to my shared hosting site going down. The website still works fine and typing in the address works fine too.

Comment: You'll need to post the actual DNS domain name for us to be of any help to you here.  But this question belongs on Superuser.com not SF.

Comment: @TheCleaner edited to show domain name

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13500/discussion-between-thecleaner-and-gaz83)